# Warning Building S3 Model Matrix Objects in R

Tags: r

Below is sample reproducible code to show a warning I am getting that I'm having trouble seeing the root cause of. The specific warning I'm writing about is "Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
non-list contrasts argument ignored"

The source of this error is in the function foo.formula. Does anyone see the root cause and a fix for this warning?

Thank you

```
foo <- function(...) UseMethod("foo")

foo.default <- function(x, y, ...){
    result <- foo.fit(x, y, ...)
    #result$call <- match.call()
    result
}

foo.formula <- function(formula, data, na.action, subset, ...){
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    m <- match(c("formula", "data", "na.action", "subset"), names(mf), 0L)
    mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
    mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
    mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
    mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
    y <- model.response(mf)
    mt <- attr(mf, "terms")
    x <- model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
    result <- foo.default(x, y, ...)
    result$call <- match.call()
    result$formula <- formula
    result
}

foo.fit <- function(x,y){
    res <- solve(crossprod(x), crossprod(x,y))
    list('coefficients' = res)
}

dat <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))

X <- model.matrix(~x + z, dat)
foo.default(X, dat$y)
foo.fit(X,dat$y)
foo(y ~ x + z, dat)
```

Comment: As far as i can see, the "contrasts" variable is neither defined nor being an argument with  default value

Comment: @RicVillalba that does seem to be correct. Removing the contrasts argument seems to make the warning go away.